# OSX : How does the system know what app to Open when connecting an iDevice or an SD card ?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

My first question is simple : How does the system know what app to open when connecting an iDevice or an SD card ?

Second question : How can I access that and maybe modify it in a Cocoa App ?

Comment: I looked into the hidden files present on one of my sd card. There is a plist : .apdisk but there is nothing in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a process called iTunes Helper that launches iTunes when an iDevice is attached. There isn't an app list for this you can edit.

For the SD Card, it's using a preference file. You can see that preferences file's contents using NSUserDefaults

```
defaults -currentHost read com.apple.ImageCapture2
```

HotPlugActionArray contains the apps to launch.

Comment: But i've to correct you, my iPhone has also a value in `com.apple.ImageCapture2`

Comment: And where does the big value (some kind of UUID ?) come from ?  (And the launched Application is more autolaunchApplicationPath, HotPlugActionArray is more like the default one when the device is connected for the first time)

Comment: Since the iPhone presents itself as a camera device, the apps in the ImageCapture preferences will launch when it's attached.

Comment: Not sure. My settings look like this: {
    HotPlugActionArray =     (
        "/Applications/Image Capture.app"
    );
    HotPlugActionPath = "/Applications/Image Capture.app";
    LastHotPlugActionPath = "";
}

Comment: I have this `{
    "4275696C-7420-496E-2053-445843205265" =     {
        ICADeviceTypeKey = ICADeviceTypeCamera;
        autolaunchApplicationPath = "/Applications/Image Capture.app";
    };
    "62633935-3666-3565-3334-366330393631" =     {
        ICADeviceTypeKey = ICADeviceTypeCamera;
        autolaunchApplicationPath = "";
    };
    HotPlugActionPath = "/Applications/iPhoto.app";
    LastHotPlugActionPath = "/Applications/iPhoto.app";
}
`(1 iPhone, 1 SD card)